# Exploding population size in neat-python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, neat

I am trying to make my AI win the board game "Catan" against my friends.
Therefore i am using the python implementation of NEAT.

As I changed the values of `weight_mutate_power`, `response_mutate_power`, `bias_mutate_power` and `compatibility_threshold` in the config the number of individuals and species exploded (~Doubled every generation and exceeded `pop_size`).

```
weight_mutate_power = 12
response_mutate_power = 0
bias_mutate_power = 0.5
compatibility_threshold = 3
```

Playing with those values I discovered that the rate of the explosion changes in relation to those values (Everything worked fine with standard Values from the documentation).

Any idea how to control this behavior? 
My cluster is drowning in genomes...

Comment: I had this same problem, and downloaded this better-implemented version of neat-python from GitHub and it fixed my problem: https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python