# Neat Python - Population size explodes because of high mutation rate

Tags: genetic-algorithms, neat

Someone has already asked a [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12778/exploding-population-size-in-neat-python) about this. But I implemented the suggestion made in the comments without success. So I was wondering if anybody had a better idea.
I changed the mutation power for the bias and the weights to 5. And the number of genomes roughly doubles after every generation. Consequently the genetic algorithm is taken ages.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title and explain in the body why your question is different from the one in the other post? Thanks.

Comment: @nbro Actually my question is not so different. Should I delete my question? Also I have found an answer myself. Should I answer in the other post?

Comment: If the answers to the other very similar question don't answer your question, then you can keep it, I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can overcome the problem of exploding population by increasing the compatibility threshold. This way one need not compromise the mutation rate.